# Strings with html tags in C#

Tags: c#, html

I have a string: `"Something {0} like this"`. This string is on html-page, but I need to insert in it for example such string: `"<a>example</a>"`, but after I look on the page in my browser I need to see:

**Something *example* like this**

*word example is reference

How I can get such result??

Comment: You should read the rules and translate the question на русский, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

`String.Format("Something {0} like this", "<a>example</a>")`

[Getting started with `String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. You have specified the place holder `{0}` so all you need now is to find a way to put a value into this place holder.

You can use `string.Format` to accomplish this:

```
string s = string.Format("Something {0} like this", "<a>example</a>");
```

I hope this helps.